# Nested asynchronous functions

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, nested

I want to get the geolocation from a client then load locations per Ajax and then display them into a list.

I have the Functions `getGeolocation`, `loadLocation` and `createList`.

`getGeolocation` and `loadLocation` are asynchronous functions and so I need Callbacks or use the Deferred Object. I searched a couple of hours on the Internet but I still don't understand the syntax of how to handle this.

I know it would be possible to call `loadLocations` in the `success` function and `createList` in the `afterResponse` function but I want to call this functions in several places and so its not an option for me.

```
var lat = 0;
var long = 0;
var locations;

getGeolocation();
loadLocations();
createList();

    $('#map').live("pageshow", function() {    
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

function getGeolocation(){    
    console.log("getGeolocation");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

             // getCurrentPosition ruft die Funktion success auf und übermittelt die Position Werte
             // error wird ausgeführt wenn es einen Fehler beim ermitteln der Position gibt
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
        alert("GeoLocation API ist NICHT verfügbar!");
    }

}

function success(position) {    
    console.log("success");
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
}

function error(msg) {    
    console.log(typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "error");
}


function loadLocations(){    
    console.log("loadLocations");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.at/api/getLocationsByGeodata_JSON",
        success: afterResponse,
        /*beforeSend: showPreloader,*/
        data: {lat : lat, long: long},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function afterResponse(response_objekt) {    
    console.log("afterResponse");
    console.log(response_objekt['results']);
    locations = response_objekt['results'];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain ` i knew it would be possible to call "loadLocations" in the "success" function and "createList" in the "afterResponse" function but I want to call this functions on many different places and so its is not a option for me`? What methods need to be called from many places?

Comment: for example i also have "createMap" function and a "showLocation" function where i want to load the locations with the same functions.

Comment: so when u call `loadLocations()` from `createMap()`, you do not want to call `createList()`, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use callback functions to achieve this

ex:

```
var lat = 0;
var long = 0;
var locations;

getGeolocation(function(){
    loadLocations().done(function(){
        createList();
    });
});

    $('#map').live("pageshow", function() {    
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

function getGeolocation(successCallback){    
    console.log("getGeolocation");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

             // getCurrentPosition ruft die Funktion success auf und übermittelt die Position Werte
             // error wird ausgeführt wenn es einen Fehler beim ermitteln der Position gibt
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCurrentPositionCallback(successCallback), error);
    } else {
        alert("GeoLocation API ist NICHT verfügbar!");
    }

}

function getCurrentPositionCallback(callback){
    return function (position) {    
        console.log("success");

        if(typeof callback == 'function'){
            callback(position);
        }

        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;
    };
}

function error(msg) {    
    console.log(typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "error");
}


function loadLocations(){    
    console.log("loadLocations");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.at/api/getLocationsByGeodata_JSON",
        success: afterResponse,
        /*beforeSend: showPreloader,*/
        data: {lat : lat, long: long},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function afterResponse(response_objekt) {    
    console.log("afterResponse");
    console.log(response_objekt['results']);
    locations = response_objekt['results'];
}
```